# Psvectorian ornaments errors

Tags: pstricks, ps

I have major errors in `psvectorian.tex` from CTAN package.
I have installed  `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\dvips\pst-vectorian\psvectorian.pro` and

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pst-vectorian\psvectorian.sty.
```

Errors are

```
*! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps*

*! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2\@@
\else \expandafter \expand...*

*! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2\@@
\else \expandafter \expand...*
```

And 155 more.
Help

Comment: Use `latex`, not `pdflatex`. I suppose you are using the later one, which is not correct

Comment: I used quickbuild in Texmaker. Now with latex i only got :    Package xkeyval Error: `couleurTexte' undefined in families `bclogo'.

Comment: well, there seems to be no such package or command option `couleurTexte` in `bclogo` package

Comment: I've found xkeyval on CTAN. I don't know how to install it. In package there is only `xkeyval.dtx` and pdf file. Readme mentioned about 10 files. I'm confused.

Comment: You most probably have `xkeyval` installed ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In `psvectorian.tex` it should most probably read `couleur` instead of `couleurTexte`. Looking into `bclogo.sty`, there is **no** `couleurTexte` key, so this most probably a typo in `psvectorian.tex`.

The compilation must be done with `latex`, not with `pdflatex`, since `pstricks` is PostScript-oriented, not designed for `pdf` mode.

The code from `psvectorian.tex` is taken from the documentation directory under CTAN/TeXLive.

I changed the line

```
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bccrayon,couleurTexte=Maroon,couleur=AliceBlue,epBord=0.4,barre=wave,blur,couleurOmbre=gray!80,couleurBarre=DarkGreen]{\titre}%
```

to

```
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bccrayon,couleur=Maroon,couleur=AliceBlue,epBord=0.4,barre=wave,blur,couleurOmbre=gray!80,couleurBarre=DarkGreen]{\titre}%



\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,frenchb]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm,headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{pstricks}
\usepackage[blur]{bclogo}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}%style fancy
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pdfstartview = FitH,colorlinks, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

%\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0,1,1}
%\pagecolor{Moccasin}

\hypersetup{% Information sur le document
pdfauthor = {P.Fradin},% Auteurs
pdftitle = {psvectorian},% Titre du document
pdfsubject = {Documentation de psvectorian},% Sujet
%pdfkeywords = {},% Mots-clefs
%pdfproducer = {}
} %

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\lhead{\rightmark}
\rhead{\textsl{psvectorian v0.4}}
\cfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}%

\title{%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{Maroon}%
\rput[r](-3pt,3pt){\psvectorian[scale=0.6]{72}}%
\Huge{Motifs d'ornements}%
\rput[l](3pt,3pt){\psvectorian[scale=0.6]{73}}\\
\psvectorian[scale=0.6]{85}%
}

\author{\href{mailto:patrick.fradin@gmail.com}{P. Fradin}}%
\newcommand*{\coloropt}{violet}
\newcommand*{\opt}[2]{\textcolor{\coloropt}{#1 = $\langle$ #2 $\rangle$}}

\newenvironment*{showCode}[1]{%
\gdef\titre{#1}%
\VerbatimOut{file.txt}}%
{%
\endVerbatimOut
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bccrayon,couleur=Maroon,couleur=AliceBlue,epBord=0.4,barre=wave,blur,couleurOmbre=gray!80,couleurBarre=DarkGreen]{\titre}%
\begin{small}%
\itshape%
\VerbatimInput{file.txt}%
\end{small}%
\end{bclogo}
\begin{center}
\input{file.txt}%
\end{center}
}%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\rput[tl](-1cm,0){\psvectorian[opacity=0.1,width=16cm]{103}}%

\begin{abstract}
Ce document dresse la liste des $196$ motifs d'ornements fournis avec le paquet \emph{psvectorian.sty}. Ceux-ci sont contenus dans le fichier prologue pour postscript \emph{psvectorian.pro}, et sont utilisables avec \emph{pstricks}. Ils ont été extraits d'un fichier \emph{eps} que l'on peut trouver sur le site:

{\centering \url{http://www.vectorian.net/} (free sample)\par}
 C'est d'ailleurs avec l'aimable autorisation de l'auteur de ce site, Vincent \textsc{Le Moign}, que ces ornements peuvent être distribués au format pstricks pour \LaTeX. 

Je remercie Herbert \textsc{Voss} pour son aide dans la mise au point de ce paquet. Je remercie également Jean-Michel \textsc{Sarlat} pour la mise à
disposition de toutes les ressources que l'on trouve sur le serveur Syracuse \url{http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/}, 
et pour tout le travail de \og mise en forme\fg{} qu'il réalise. Je remercie également Juergen \textsc{Gilg} qui est à l'origine de l'option \emph{opacity}.
\end{abstract}

\hfil\psvectorian[height=2mm]{88}\hfil

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{14cm}%
\tableofcontents
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\bigskip
\hfil\psvectorian[height=2mm]{88}\hfil

\vfill

\hfil\psvectorian[scale=0.95,color=Maroon]{60}\hfil

\vfill

\clearpage

\section{La macro \emph{psvectorian}}

L'affichage d'un motif à l'endroit $(x,y)$ se fait avec la macro \verb|\rput| de \emph{pstricks}, de la manière suivante:\par\medskip
{\centering \textbf{$\backslash$rput[refpoint]\{angle\}(x,y)\{$\backslash$psvectorian[options]\{numéro\}\} }\par}
\medskip

La macro \verb|\psvectorian[options]{numéro}| dessine le motif correspondant au numéro demandé, celui-ci doit être entre $1$ et $196$. Cette macro peut aussi s'utiliser seule, elle représente un environnement \emph{pspicture} qui sera donc placé au point courant. Les options possibles sont:

\medskip
\begin{itemize}
\item \opt{scale}{échelle}. L'échelle est un nombre entre $0$ et $1$ ($1$ par défaut).
\item \opt{opacity}{nombre}. L'opacité est un nombre entre $0$ et $1$ qui permet d'avoir de la transparence lorsque celui-ci est strictement inférieur à $1$  ($1$ par défaut).
\item \opt{width}{nombre+unité} permet d'imposer une largeur. Si la hauteur n'est pas précisée, alors le ratio est conservé.
\item \opt{height}{nombre+unité} permet d'imposer une hauteur. Si la largeur n'est pas précisée, alors le ratio est conservé.
\item \opt{color}{couleur} permet de définir la couleur du motif. Par défaut la couleur est définie par la macro \verb|\psvectorianDefaultColor|, cette macro peut-être redéfinie par l'utilisateur, elle contient la couleur \emph{black} au chargement du paquet.
\item \opt{flip}{true/false}. Avec la valeur \emph{true} le motif subit une symétrie axiale, l'axe est horizontal et passe par le centre de la boîte englobante. La valeur par défaut est \emph{false}.
\item \opt{mirror}{true/false}. Avec la valeur \emph{true} le motif subit une symétrie axiale, l'axe est vertical et passe par le centre de la boîte englobante. La valeur par défaut est \emph{false}.
\end{itemize}


\section{Exemples}

\begin{showCode}{Dans un \emph{pspicture}}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{blue}%
\psframe[linewidth=0.4pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Beige](-5,-5)(5,5)%
%haut+bas
\rput[tl](-3,5){\psvectorian[width=6cm]{71}}
\rput[bl](-3,-5){\psvectorian[width=6cm,flip]{71}}
%coins
\rput[tl](-5,5){\psvectorian[width=2cm]{63}}
\rput[tr](5,5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,mirror]{63}}
\rput[bl](-5,-5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,flip]{63}}
\rput[br](5,-5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,flip,mirror]{63}}
% cotes
\rput[bl]{-90}(-5,3){\psvectorian[width=6cm]{46}}
\rput[bl]{90}(5,-3){\psvectorian[width=6cm]{46}}
%texte+soulignement+chapeau
\rput(0,0){\Huge Ornaments}
\rput[t](0,-0.5){\psvectorian[width=5cm]{75}}
\rput[b](0,0.5){\psvectorian[width=5cm]{69}}
%oiseaux
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1,2.5){\psvectorian[width=2cm]{113}}
\rput[tl]{30}(1,2.5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,mirror]{113}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{showCode}

\bigskip

\begin{showCode}{Hors d'un \emph{pspicture}}
\rput[r](0pt,3pt){\psvectorian[color=black,height=1cm]{102}}%
\Large Texte%
\rput[l](0pt,3pt){\psvectorian[color=black,height=1cm,mirror]{102}}% 
\end{showCode}


\section{La liste des motifs}


\begin{showCode}{Code}
\newcounter{compt}\setcounter{compt}{1}%
\loop
\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}m{6.25cm}m{1cm}m{6.25cm}}
\ifnum\thecompt<90\gdef\scl{0.325}\else\gdef\scl{1}\fi%
\tiny{\No\thecompt:}&\hfil\psvectorian[scale=\scl]{\thecompt}\hfil&
\addtocounter{compt}{1}
\ifnum\thecompt<90\gdef\scl{0.325}\else\gdef\scl{1}\fi%
\hfill\tiny{\No\thecompt:}&
\hfil\psvectorian[scale=\scl]{\thecompt}\hfil\\
\end{tabular}\par
\ifnum\thecompt<196 \addtocounter{compt}{1}
\repeat
\end{showCode}

\end{document}
```

The screen shot below shows just one part of the document, not all of it. However.

[image]

Comment: I got `! Package frenchb.ldf Error: frenchb requires babel v.3.9i.
(frenchb.ldf) Aborting here` ,   `! Undefined control sequence.
l.79 ...ur tout le travail de \og mise en forme\fg Undefined control sequence.
\iterate ...25}\else \gdef \scl {1}\fi \tiny {\No
\thecompt :}&\hfil \psvect...l.12 \repeat `

Comment: @vejn: Well, what should I do now? ;-) It compiles on my machine, having the latest packages...

Comment: @vejn: I suppose so, but I am not using MikTeX or Windows

Comment: @vejn Do you have a mixture of different package versions? Multiple installations of TeX? A system TeX installation with a bunch of packages installed in your personal TEXMF tree? If the version of `frenchb.ldf` is out of sync with the version of `babel`, you have serious issues with your setup which have nothing to do with the particular issue in this question.

Comment: I have only Miktex. I have send a request for releasing Miktex 3. I have update it via manager but errors still occurs. Where should I update from?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple template that I just setup for a a5 size paper for using psvectorian - I compile it with xelatex and it works fine. Use the grid for positioning the ornaments.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,twoside,onecolumn,openany,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\newcommand{\owl}[1][]{\psvectorian[#1]{123}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,12)%
\psgrid[griddots=5, subgriddiv=0]
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{blue}%
%\psframe[fillcolor=Beige,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12)%
\psframe(-5,-5)(5,12)%
%top and bottom center
\rput[tl](-3,12){\psvectorian[width=6cm,flip]{85}}
\rput[bl](-3,-5){\psvectorian[width=6cm]{85}}
%four corners
\rput[tl](-5,12){\psvectorian[width=2cm]{61}}
\rput[tr](5,12){\psvectorian[width=2cm,mirror]{61}}
\rput[bl](-5,-5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,flip]{61}}
\rput[br](5,-5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,flip,mirror]{61}}
% sides
\rput[bl]{-90}(-5,9){\psvectorian[width=11cm]{88}}
\rput[bl]{90}(5,-2){\psvectorian[width=11cm]{88}}
%texte+above text+below text
\rput(0,8){\Huge Ornaments}
\rput[b](0,8.5){\psvectorian[width=5cm]{69}}
\rput[t](0,7.5){\psvectorian[width=5cm]{75}}
\rput(0,-4){Testing}
\end{pspicture}%
\clearpage
 \bigskip
 \rput[r](0pt,3pt){\psvectorian[color=black,height=1cm]{62}}%
\Large Texte%
\rput[l](0pt,3pt){\psvectorian[color=black,height=1cm,mirror]{62}}% 
 \bigskip
 \begin{center}
  \psvectorian[width=.3\textwidth,height=\baselineskip]{47}
\end{center}
\hfil\psvectorian[scale=0.95,color=Maroon]{60}\hfil
 \vfill
 \clearpage

\end{document}
```

Here is how the output looks:

[image: PSvectorian Example]