# Psvectorian problem

Tags: pstricks, psvectorian

Could you provide me a MWE for using psvectorian package?

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\begin{document}
  \psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}
\end{document}
```

It gives back this error message:

```
Undefined control sequence. \psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}
```

Maybe the installation of the package is not complete. How can I install psvectorian properly?

Comment: Are you compiling with `latex` or `xelatex`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, in addition.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`psvectorian` ornaments errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235614/5764)

Comment: The undefined control sequence that's reported is `\c@lor@to@ps`, not `\psvectorian`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requires `latex` or `xelatex` since it makes use of PostScript `\specials` (being a PsTricks package) not available with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\begin{document}
\psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}
\end{document}
```

If it should be compiled with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, use the package `auto-pst-pdf` in addition to provide the automatic conversion to `.pdf`. In any case, `--enable-write18` or `--shell-escape` must be enabled for this!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\psvectorian[height=1cm]{102}
\end{document}
```

[image]