# psvectorian package

Tags: packages, miktex, psvectorian

I work with Miktex2.9 . In a template code I downloaded , their is something called a `psvectorian` package. i.e. it uses `\usepackage{psvectorian}`   .However I searched the `Miktex` package manager, but could not find a single package named like that. What am I to do?

If you want specifically, I can enclose in the code, but I did not , as it would make the post unnecessarily huge..

Edit: I have installed all the packages of Miktex 2.9 . Still code is not working

Comment: `psvectorian` is perhaps in the `pstricks` bundle (if this is called that way in MikTeX -- I've no idea, but `psvectorian` requires `pstricks`!)

Comment: Well, is the package not found or is the code not working? Try to compile with `latex`, not with `pdflatex` -- if it's a compilation problem, please have a look on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254385/psvectorian-problem

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : Well , this worked ! but my problem doesn't end here. How am I to generate the pdf?

Comment: See my answer under the link I provided above -- the answer has a clue how to use `pdflatex` by `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: With reference to your link, how to enable write18 or --shell-espace in Texstudio?

Comment: I've have never used TeXStudio. Normally this is a `MikTeX` or `TeXLive` setting, so `pdflatex --shell-escape` does it under Linux, for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : Can you help me in some way? As you may have understood, I use Windows 7, so in texStudio, there is usually no place for giving commands like the one you mentioned? Or can you refer this question to someone who has used TexStudio?

Comment: I've just installed TeXStudio -- go to Options/Configure TeXStudio/--> Commands --> you should see a Textfield for pdflatex with `pdflatex --synctex ....` just enter `--shell-escape` between `pdflatex` and `--syntex` -- this should work

Comment: I just noticed: Under MikTeX it's called `--enable-write18` apparently

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure TeX Studio, goto  Options > configure TeX Studio > Commands`and add`--enable-write18` to the pdflatex switches in the relevant line, like this:

[image]